# Visual Studio 2013 update 5 designer won't load

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have Windows 8.1. I installed Visual Studio 2013 update 5. When I run `MainPage.xaml.cs` in a new project, designer won't load. Below is a screenshot. Is there any solution?

[image]

Comment: i think its not been installed correctly, because its asking for a package which is not there in ur system..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You messed up your VS installation, it can't find its own debugger libraries. I don't think there is much you can do but uninstall it all and reinstall from scratch.